# Using Hyper On A Page With Validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, validation, master-pages

I have a hyperlink on my master page that directs me to the homepage.

It works on every page except a page that has validators.

How do I make the hyperlink work?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what doesn't work. Can you post some code that can give little insight into the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it is a hyperlink and not a linkbutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information would be helpful, but I have a suggestion: make sure the hyperlink doesn't have a property called "CausesValidation" = True.  A hyperlink control causes a post, which will trigger a validator.  Turn it off and you should be good to go.